# Halting problem is undecidable proof-:

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, halting-problem

Confused with this proof. I will point my confusions here.

[image]

what is R(M)? They say it is representation of turing machine but what is it exactly? Is it tuples of turing machine? How do we decide w is input here? Because later when doing R(M)*R(M) we call R(M) as input.

[image]

how can we just assume that H'-:

when M halts with input w, loops

when M does not hal with input w, halt?

What logic are we using while making H' from H? Can you tell me about that?

[image]

why did we made a copy? was it to get input as R(M)? I don't know how and why about that though I am just looking at R(M)*w and thinking if we get R(M)*R(M) the input will be R(M).

[image]

From M halts we get to D halts, how can we say so?

It is still M not?

https://slideplayer.com/slide/10708471/

Comment: In such cases I recommend watching [Proof that Computers Can't Do Everything](https://youtu.be/92WHN-pAFCs).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer the many questions you have here to the best of my ability:

> what is R(M)? They say it is representation of turing machine but what is it exactly? Is it tuples of turing machine?

It is some representation of some Turing Machine $M$. The exact format of the representation is not important for this proof, just that it unambiguously specifies a particular Turing Machine.

> How do we decide w is input here?

We do not "decide" any input. We are trying to prove by contradiction that there exists no TM $H$ that solves the Halting Problem; so we begin by assuming such $H$ exists and therefore works correctly for any representation of TM $R(M)$ and input $w$. $w$ can be any string but will be the string representation of a Turing Machine in the further construction of this proof.

> What logic are we using while making H' from H? Can you tell me about that?

Suppose you were given the state transition table for $H$. All you need to do is to replace the accepting state(s) of $H$ with an infinitely looping state. This is your $H'$. Now, clearly for any input, $H'$ loops if and only if $H$ accepts the same input, halts otherwise.

> why did we made a copy? was it to get input as R(M)?

Exactly so. $D$ simulates $H'$ with the input $R(M), R(M)$. $D$'s ultimate behavior emerges from the $H'$ we constructed earlier: if $R(M)$ halts with the input $R(M)$, $H'$ doesn't halt so neither does $D$. But if $R(M)$ does *not* halt with the input $R(M)$, $H'$ halts and so does $D$.

In other words, $D$ is a Turing machine that, given some representation of a Turing Machine $R(M)$ as input, halts if and only if $M$ does *not* halt when given $R(M)$ as input, and otherwise. We arrive at a contradiction by having $R(D)$ being given to $D$ itself as input.

> From M halts we get to D halts, how can we say so?

Notice we are giving $R(D)$ as input to $D$. Therefore $H'$ executes with $R(D), R(D)$ as input. What happens next? Either:

- $H'$ loops forever, which means $H$ says $D$ halts on the input $R(D)$, in which case $H$ was wrong, OR
- $H'$ halts, which means $H$ says $D$ doesn't halt on the input $R(D)$, in which case $H$ is also wrong

So we have a contradiction from assuming the existence of $H$ – therefore such TM cannot exist.

Comment: We made H' such that if H in accept=>Loop. How can we make sth like this? What is the logic behind this? This looks trying too hard to prove sth and looks illogical to me tbh.

Also what are you telling at conclusion I didn't get it really. You say H says D halts on input R(D) and say H was wrong, why was H wrong?

Comment: @supcem I explain in my answer how $H'$ is defined, it's a simple modification to the putative $H$'s state transition function. As for why $H$ is wrong: no matter which way it predicts $D$ as executing, we have engineered a situation where its prediction is wrong.